# Filter multi-key dimension with dc.selectmenu

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have attempted to extend this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rn3ja9n4/
here
https://jsfiddle.net/thyfoubq/32/

but it is unclear what I should use to power the dc.selectmenu or if the it is even capable of working in the multi-key scenario.

Is this possible?
I have tried several variations of this but i can't seem to get the filter to work with the composite key or the single branch key

```
  var storedim =ndx.dimension(function(d){ return [d.store]})
   var storegroup =storedim.group()
   storeselect
    .dimension(storedim)
     .group(storegroup)
    .multiple(true)
    .size(5)
    .controlsUseVisibility(true)
    .title(kv => kv.key);
```

----------------------- possible solution that appears to work---------
---change the group to remove empty bins

```
var suppliersSumGroup = remove_empty_bins(suppliersSumDistinct.group().reduceSum( d => d.earnings ));

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
return {
all:function () {
    return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
        return d.value !=0;  //appears to work borrowed from another SO post 
                     //unsure which one but it seems logical and works for this example
    });
}
};
}
```

Comment: To answer my own question remove_unused bins as used in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/thyfoubq/46/  not sure if this is the best or correct implementation but it works comments>?function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
return {
    all:function () {
        return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
            return d.value !=0;
        });
    }
};
}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thyfoubq/48/ is the original fiddle with just the changes above and the alternate non-overlapping data commented out and the original data resotored